# Kafka-Node in Node fetchMaxBytes parameter

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Does anyone know what 2 parameters in the fetchMaxBytes represent? 
If its represented as 1024*1024, does that mean that the consumer will fetch 1024 messages of each 1Kb? Or will it jest fetch 1Mb of messages?

I was not able to find any relevant information from the documentation except this: "*The maximum bytes to include in the message set for this partition. This helps bound the size of the response.*"

I need this parameter to get messages one by one rather than getting a couple of messages in a single shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with `node.js` but I assume `fetchMaxBytes` corresponds to `replicate.fetch.max.bytes`. For this case, the value is the maximum buffer size (in bytes, ie, 1024*1024 = 1MB) for fetching messages. A buffer can contain multiple messages of arbitrary size. It basically means, wait for fetching not longer as "until a buffer got filled up".

Comment: After playing around with it a bit and posting it as a question in their git page i got the answer. It represents the max size to be filled up..it will fetch 'x' number of messages whose size totals to 1Mb